# neo4j driver functions equivalent to py2neo functions

Tags: python, graph-databases, py2neo, rasa, neo4j-driver

```
def get_nlg(graph_query):
    driver = Graph("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j","password"))
    graph_response = graph.evaluate(graph_query)
```

For the above code, I replaced with the driver code as below, but its not working, what is the function in neo4j driver equivalent to **evaluate()** function in py2neo?

```
    def get_nlg(graph_query):
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j","password"))

        with driver.session() as session:
            graph_response = session.run(graph_query)
            return graph_response
```

When the result from **graph_response** of 2nd code is passed to the below code, I am getting an error

> TypeError: <neo4j.work.result.Result object at 0x7f94cf7f31d0> is not JSON serializable

```
class GetBiggestComponent(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_get_biggest_component"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        query = None
        intent = tracker.latest_message['intent']
        child_comp = tracker.get_slot('component_type_child')
        parent_comp = tracker.get_slot('component_type_parent')
        error = None
        graph_response = GenerateQuery.get_biggest_component(child_comp, parent_comp)
        graph_response['intent_name'] = intent['name']
        dispatcher.utter_custom_message(graph_response)
        return []
```

the error is coming when it is passed in the line

```
dispatcher.utter_custom_message(graph_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent. You will need to `run` a query and then select the first value from the first record returned. That is all that `evaluate` does behind the scenes.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get first value from the first record when using the function ```run```?

Comment: maybe a bit late, but if you make a "run" you will get back an cursor object. You can handle the cursor object by usage of something like 

`while cursor.forward():   result = cursor.current.data()`

here the documentation: [https://py2neo.org/2021.1/cypher/index.html#py2neo.cypher.Cursor](https://py2neo.org/2021.1/cypher/index.html#py2neo.cypher.Cursor)