# How to get the result using neo4j-driver functions as same as the result from evaluate() function in py2neo?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo, rasa, neo4j-driver

```
def get_nlg(graph_query):
    driver = Graph("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j","password"))
    graph_response = graph.evaluate(graph_query)
```

For the above code, I replaced with the driver code as below, but its not working, what is the function in neo4j driver equivalent to **evaluate()** function in py2neo?

```
    def get_nlg(graph_query):
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j","password"))

        with driver.session() as session:
            graph_response = session.run(graph_query)
            return graph_response
```

When the result from **graph_response** of 2nd code is passed to the below code, I am getting an error

> TypeError: <neo4j.work.result.Result object at 0x7f94cf7f31d0> is not JSON serializable

```
class GetBiggestComponent(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_get_biggest_component"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        query = None
        intent = tracker.latest_message['intent']
        child_comp = tracker.get_slot('component_type_child')
        parent_comp = tracker.get_slot('component_type_parent')
        error = None
        graph_response = GenerateQuery.get_biggest_component(child_comp, parent_comp)
        graph_response['intent_name'] = intent['name']
        dispatcher.utter_message(json.dumps(graph_response))
        return []
```

the error is coming when it is passed in the line

```
dispatcher.utter_message(json.dumps(graph_response))
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64800042/neo4j-driver-functions-equivalent-to-py2neo-functions

Answer (score 0):

The output of `session.run` is an object that lets you navigate the result, not the result itself. I strongly recommend reading the manual and API docs for the driver, as this is all described in there.

- https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/session-api/simple/#driver-simple-result-consume
- https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#result

As per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64818875/823822) to your other question, to simulate `evaluate`, you will simply need to navigate to the first record of the result and then return the first value of that record.